# Текст ошибки в случае ввода слишком длинного ника выводится на португальском (sic!) языке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще, насколько я могу судить, там должны быть [эти строки](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/144561641?q=text%3A'Display%20Name%20must%20be%20no%20more%20than'). Но их ещё не заапрувили. Но, в любом случае, не понимаю, откуда там португальский взялся.

Comment: А как удалось ввести более 30 символов? Там же у поля ограничение. Модификация html?

Comment: @alexolut  ага..

Comment: А на других сайтах не проверяли? Может проблема достойна MSE.

Comment: @alexolut других локализованных? Проверял только на en SO, там "Display Name must be no more than 30 characters" выводится.

Comment: @alexolut у испанцев es.stackoverflow.com вообще не переведено, у них там английский текст.

Comment: А у японцев как? :)

Comment: @alexolut https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2752/30081 английский

Comment: @alexolut да даже у самих португальцев там на английском лол

Comment: @alexolut сейчас там "Длинаотображаемого имени не должна превышать 30 символов" (с ошибкой, слова слитно). В трансе не вижу таких строк =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С последней выкаткой переводов всё поправилось.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Было бы интересно узнать, как оно вообще просочилось.

Comment: @alexolut мне тоже. И кто поправил, причём, в первый раз с ошибкой)